# Nginx proxy_cache_purge alternative - get file out of cache

Tags: nginx, proxy

I seems that the `proxy_cache_purge` directive is supported only in the commercial nginx version.

**Is there an alternative way I could get a file/path/key out of the cache?**

Below my sample `proxy_pass` configuration with enabled caching:

```
...

# Configure proxy cache
proxy_cache_path    /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=demo:10m;

proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:90$uri;

proxy_set_header    Host $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_cache         demo;
# proxy_cache off;

proxy_cache_key     $host$uri$is_args$args;
proxy_cache_valid   any 1m;

...
```

Comment: Do you really need to purge cache or just force nginx to refresh cache? For latter you could use [`proxy_cache_bypass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass)

Comment: @AlexeyTen what is the difference between purge and bypass? The documentation says: Defines conditions under which the response will not be taken from a cache. Does it mean that the new (bypassed) response will be now stored in the cache?

Comment: Yes, it will be stored.

Comment: Purge just remove item from cache. It will not get new version from backend

Comment: Please put Your comment as an answer. I think others could profit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to force nginx to refresh cache, you could use [`proxy_cache_bypass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass). It will make nginx to fetch new data from backend and put them in cache.

Comment: As the name of the directive suggests, it only *bypasses* the cache, i.e. directly going to upstream server for response but does *not* update the cache. Unfortunately the directive in the paid version is exactly what OP needed.